# Can't convert 'sre.SRE_Pattern' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp, typeerror

I have a list of sentences that I want to clean and rid of URL's, numbers, unwanted special characters, etc. I am trying the code below to clean out URL's.

```
import re

return_words = []
for counter, value in enumerate(my_words):
    temp = [w.replace((re.compile(r"http.?://[^\s]+[\s]?")), "") for w in value]
    return_words.append(temp)
    return return_words
```

I am getting a TypeError saying Can't convert 'sre.SRE_Pattern' object to str implicitly. Could someone please help me and point me in the right direction?

Comment: The compiled regex object created by `re.compile()` has a `sub()` method to do replacements.

Comment: That was so easy, and I feel so dumb right now. Thanks!